# jquery .find() is not returning value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have gone through this before, but I don't know what I am doing wrong. I also take a look the documentation plus the existing question on Stack Overflow but I could not find any answer. This drives me crazy. I know I missed something but I could not trace it. This is what I have in index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>

<?php
echo '<table border="1" width="50%">';
foreach($datas as $data){
    echo '<form method="post" action="" class="vForm">';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1" size="3" /></td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="add" value="add" class="button" /></td></tr>';
    echo '</form>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

So in my file.js

```
$(function() {
    var CA = (function() {

        function add(form) {
            console.log('Form: ' + form.find('[name="qty"]').val() );
            return false;
        }

        $('.vForm').submit(function(e) {
            add($(this));
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    }());
});
```

For some reason I could not able to get the "qty" value in the text field in file.js. The code below also failed. I just got "undefined" in the console log.

```
console.log('Form: ' + form.find('input[name="qty"]').val() );
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try wrapping your js around `$(document).ready`

Comment: @KarlViiburg $(function() { does the same thing

Comment: @DemoUser It does? Sorry about that, guess you learn something every day. THanks on the tip.

Comment: Try logging the result of `form` in the `add();` function and see what you get

Comment: I didn't think `.val()` ever returned `undefined`. Could you log `form.find('input[name="qty"]')`?

Comment: @Scimonster `.val()` returns `undefined` when the jQuery result set is empty.

Comment: @Nunners I got values for `console.log(form)` 
@Scimonster I got `[object Object]` when I log `form.find('input[name="qty"]')`

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/csgjvu2p/

Comment: And me : http://jsfiddle.net/bLj2m5hf/

Comment: @DemoUser yes that is on purpose. I will have many forms containing each entry.

Comment: yes guys all of yours are working. I wonder why mine is not.

Comment: @UserProg Are you sure that the code you are using is **exactly** the same as what you are showing us?

Comment: Just asking... Do you have linked jQuery? Even if the jQuery code to get the value is not working you should get `Form: ` logged. If you make an alert instead of the console.log, will it run?

Comment: Can you show us the HTML of the script tag, where you are adding it in the HTML and such.

Comment: yes the codes are same, I have double check and I am going to check it again. I have updated the script tag. I do have jQuery and the file.js is included as well

Comment: @UserProg Same result on all browsers?

Comment: @Daedalus Wow the result is fine in I.E. But not on Chrome which I am using right now. Now I can see `Form: <the figure>`. How is that possible?

Comment: @UserProg Use chrome's incognito mode and see if the problem persists.  If it does not, then it is a plugin in your browser interfering with your code.

Comment: @Daedalus OK incognito mode also returned `undefined`. What should I do next? I have no experience in this kind of problem before.

Comment: @UserProg That is unfortunate.  That's what I was banking on, the only other thing I can really think of at this moment is if you're not using the latest chrome, but some beta version of it or something.  I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: @UserProg You could try clearing Chrome's browser cache and see if the problem continues. It may be a corrupted file or something.

Comment: The code *as shown* appears fine in all browsers, however you are wrapping it in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) *then* assigning the return value (of `undefined`) to `CA`. **Is your example complete as that code makes no sense?**

Comment: This is really unfortunate. My Chrome is up to date, I already cleaned up the cache and everything, and still the result is `undefined`. @TrueBlueAussie they are part of my code which is not really complete yet, I build this gradually. I will not proceed further if this has not been solved. I took this from Internet, I don't know IIFE by the way.

Comment: Re IIFE: An IIFE is a function you wrap in brackets and call immediately and looks like this `(function(){...})()`. The return result is whatever that function returns (which in your case there is no value returned). Can you try your own code in a JSFiddle *of your own* and provide that here as nobody seems to be able to reproduce your problem. It may be something else you have not shown us. Use Save-As from a browser to get the output HTML (more useful than the PHP source).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have now found the reason. Actually, I wrap up the display of the `$datas` in a table (sorry that I did not put the table code in the question, my mistake guys). That is why it is not taking the value. When I remove the `<table>` it works. Any explanation on this.

Comment: Update your question to include all relevant details please.

Comment: Question updated, thank you. When I remove `table` with `tr` and `td` it works.

Comment: Thank you everybody for spending your time on my issue. Definitely I learned something from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after reading the comments section, and after the actual code is provided..  I believe the reason is quite simple:

The form element is not a valid child of the table element.  Your code basically, renders the following.

```
<table>
    <form method="post" action="" class="vForm">
      <tr>
          <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1" size="3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="add" class="button" /></td>
      </tr>
  </form>
</table>
```

As stated in the [W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TABLE), the only valid children of the table element are 'caption', 'col' or 'colgroup', 'thead', 'tfoot', or 'tbody'.

I don't know how jQuery's `.find()` method specifically works, when it gets to how jQuery is programmed, but fixing this invalid html results in your desired effect:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="vForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty" value="1" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="add" value="add" class="button" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

[Demo, illustrating the above(check your console)](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/ad0g3tdz/1/).

Comment: I would like to note that your problem is reproduced with invalid html, but more than that, even though the above is in itself, technically invalid, it still works, in part, I'm sure, due to how browsers render html.

Comment: Also, if anyone is able to find why the tr element is a seemingly valid child of a table in the w3c specification, please link the relevant documentation, as I can't find it.

Comment: Now I understand the problem, thank you to your explanation. Yes it is related to the structure of `table` and `form`. Maybe I should look back into my code and think of how to restructure it. I will accept your answer. Thank you everybody for helping me out.

Answer (score -2):

MY dear friend it is working fine.

```
<?php 
$datas=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
foreach($datas as $data){
echo '<form method="post" action="" class="vForm">';
echo '<input type="text" name="qty" value="'.$data.'" size="3" />';
echo '<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" class="button" />';
echo '</form>';
} 
?>
```

Please check the screen shot and in input area i took the $data's value.[image]

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. I've posted a similar comment, with a link to jsfiddle.